# SQL TO Linq, How to return an object and fill properties

Tags: c#, sql, linq

i have a question, i want to create a linq query that returns a list of object.

This is the model

```
public class Test
{
[Key]
public int ID { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(5)]
public string Code { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(50)]
public string Name { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public string Reference { get; set; }
}
```

The query that i want to do is simple: context.Test.ToList();
this returns the database mapping Reference is null since is not part of the table.

Now if i create a linq query i know that i can do select new { all fields here }
i want to avoid this:

```
select new Test
{
Reference = r,
ID = t.ID,
Code = t.Code,
Name = t.Name
}).ToList();
```

is it possible to do something like this

```
(from t in context.Test
join r in context.Reference on f.ID equals r.ID
select new
{
  t.Reference = r.Reference,
  t
}).ToList();
```

i want to set the Reference value inside the same query, is that possible?

Comment: Please look at the following link, probably it will give you some idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63980174/stuck-into-include-limitation-need-to-join-by-custom-fields-in-addition-to-ke?noredirect=1#comment113136920_63980174

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are you asking is not directly supported in LINQ to Entities - neither projection to entity type, nor expression block which is the only way to assign properties of an existing object.

As usual, the typical workaround is to split the query on two parts - one being LINQ to Entities query selecting the necessary data (usually into intermediate anonymous type), then switch to LINQ to Objects with `AsEnumerable()` and do the rest - in this case using block inside `Select`:

```
var result = 
    (from t in context.Test
     join r in context.Reference on f.ID equals r.ID
     select new { t, r.Reference }
    ).AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x =>
    {
        x.t.Reference = x.Reference;
        return x.t;
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't select an anonymous object, just create a new T from the one you have.

```
(from t in context.Test
join r in context.Reference on t.ID equals r.ID
select new Test
{
  Reference = r,
  ID = t.ID,
  Code = t.Code,
  Name = t.Name
}).ToList();
```

EDIT:

To avoid having to manually copy over all the properties

```
public class Test
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Reference { get; set; }

    public Test CopyWithReference(string reference)
    {
        var copy = (Test)this.MemberwiseClone();
        copy.Reference = reference;
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Then...

```
(from t in context.Test
join r in context.Reference on t.ID equals r.ID
select t.CopyWithReference(r)).ToList();
```

Comment: Not possible if I'm inside generic, where T is an abstract base type. So it's not a universal approach. First answer is a preferable way

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
(from t in context.Test
join r in context.Reference on f.ID equals r.ID
select new Test() 
{
  ID = t.ID,
  Code = t.Code,
  Name = t.Name,
  Reference = r.Reference
}).ToList();
```

Comment: That is what i want yo avoid, having to put all fields, in this example they are only 3 fields but they are more. Is something better? or we have to select new and add  each field.?

Comment: The only other way is to pass the values as an array in the constructor parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var result = context.Test.Include("Reference").ToList();
```

or:

```
var result = context.Test.Include(t => t.Reference).ToList();
```

or Try Lambda Expressions:

```
var result = context.Test.Select(t => new {
                                t,
                                t.Reference = t.Reference.Select(r => new { 
                                              r.Reference })
             }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.r).ToList();
```

Comment: If we want to fill properties using our custom JOIN - it's better not to use 'Include', since if we use Include - EF adds outer select and corresponding JOIN defined in model binding (via HasMany, HasOne). IMHO.