# Stuck into "Include" limitation (need to join by custom fields in addition to key fields)

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, left-join

I have the following class:

```
public class A {
  public B B_a_1 { get; set; }
  ...
  public B B_a_[N] { get; set; }
}

public class C {
  public B B_c_1 { get; set; }
  ...
  public B B_c_[M] { get; set; }
}
```

Class **B** is mapped to the table via `OnModelCreating` and has a composite key. But one of the fields in this key is a *language code*: in some cases it's a *current thread* language, in other cases all languages need to be selected - for instance, when admin is going to edit localizations (it's a client-created DB for many years and the structure is not going to be changed). This poses the problem of data selection for me. I cannot use `Include` as-is, because *Language code* needs to be joined conditionally. Due to large amount of different kinds of **B** entities (which differ by *code* - one of key fields) I cannot create a .NET class per each **B** entity, inheriting it from base class and use `HasDiscriminator`, `HasQueryFilter` in base class and stuff like that. In fact, what I now need is to select specific type of **B** entity by *code*, using some *Extension* method like that (pseudo-code is following):

```
DbSet<A>.Include(x => x.B_a_1).Where(x => x.B_a_1.LanguageCode = "E").Include(x => x.B_a_[N]).Where(x => x.B_a_[N].SomeProperty = "Something")
```

which would be translated to:

```
FROM Table_A a
LEFT JOIN Table_B b1 ON b1.Code = a.Code AND b1.LanguageCode = 'E'
LEFT JOIN Table_B b2 ON b2.Code = a.Code AND b2.SomeProperty = 'Something'
```

I need to 'group' `include`-`where` to be able to independently control *JOIN* conditions per each **B**-kind entity.

Comment: Please show *working* code as a [mcve] with proper types and property names. Pseudo code is too ambiguous.

Comment: Sorry, EF (Core) supports only physical FK relationships. Logical (or polymorphic) relations like described here were never supported by EF and now EF Core. You might post feature request on their GitHub repo and wait to eventually be implemented some day if there are enough votes for it, so they see a value of doing that. But as of now, you are stuck with manual joins (no relationships/navigation properties and related sugar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following approach.

Having for instance the class **ModuleLanguage** with child entity **Language**, which cannot be explicitly bound via key relationship:

```
public class ModuleLanguage
{
    ...
    public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
    public FixCodeValue Language { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

1. I ignore such property in model creation:

   ```
       builder.Entity<ModuleLanguage>(b =>
       {
            b.Ignore(x => x.Language);
       }
   ```
2. manual load this property (**FixCodeValue** class is actually used by many child entities and all of them need to be selected from the same DB table, but based on different criteria):

   ```
        var currentLanguageCode = DbContext.CurrentLanguage;

        await query.ForEachAsync(moduleLanguage =>
        {
            moduleLanguage.Language = DbContext.FixCodeValues
                .FirstOrDefault(language =>
                    language.DomainId == CentralToolsDomainTypes.CentralTools
                    && language.CodeName == CentralToolsFieldTypes.LANGUAGE
                    && language.StringValue == moduleLanguage.LanguageCode
                    && language.LanguageCode == currentLanguageCode);
        });
   ```